# Contact Form Submit doesn't show Sender's Information

Tags: php, forms, contact-form, form-processing

I use a PHP file to process a **contact form**. It works, but I just receive the content of the email that is sent.

**Name and email of the sender** won't show up, which would make it really difficult to stay in touch.

```php
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";
$name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = $success = "";

//form is submitted with POST method
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $name_error = "Name is required";
  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
      $name_error = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $email_error = "Email is required";
  } else {
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    // check if e-mail address is well-formed
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $email_error = "Invalid email format"; 
    }
  }


  if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $message = "";
  } else {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }

  if ($name_error == '' and $email_error == '' and $phone_error == '' and $url_error == '' ){
      $message_body = '';
      unset($_POST['submit']);
      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
          $message_body .=  "$key: $value\n";
      }

      $to = 'yummy@njoki.de';
      $subject = 'Contact Form Submit';
      if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $email, $name)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
      }
  }

}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious about `$name_error = $email_error = $phone_error = $url_error = "";`, is this a correct syntax?

Comment: @Swellar Yes, this is correct.

Comment: @Swellar yes it is. I do often when declare and define multiple var on the same value

Comment: Cool, that's a useful code. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP mail function

> mail(to,subject,message,headers,parameters);

Change your if statement to following

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $message_body)){
          $success = "Message sent, thank you for contacting us!";
          $name = $email = $phone = $message = $url = '';
      }
```

In $message_body you have already set all the values including name and email.